# Property 'userAgentData' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome

Since navigator.userAgent's information will be reduced so I want to migrate to User-Agent Client Hints but it shows error like this:

[image]

How do I solve this, please help. Many thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't ship with type declarations for the experimental [`Navigator.userAgentData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData) property by default.

You could install e.g. [this package](https://github.com/lukewarlow/user-agent-data-types#readme) which claims to add the types [or just look at its implementation](https://github.com/lukewarlow/user-agent-data-types/blob/master/index.d.ts) to see how to write the [declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html) yourself.

Answer (score 12):

You need to install types for Navigator.userAgentData

1. Install user agent types from npm:

   `npm i -D user-agent-data-types`
2. In the tsconfig.json add:

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [
      "./node_modules/user-agent-data-types"
     ]
   },
}
```

Now you should be able to see `userAgentData` property on navigator object.

Comment: I also needed to make the same `types` change in `tsconfig.spec.json` for the app to build without error.

Answer (score 3):

I think typescript doesn't have declaration support for userAgentData now.
Time being use type assertion `as any` .

eg : `(window.navigator as any).userAgentData`

Answer (score 2):

you can use Next.js

- Install user agent types

```bash
npm i -D user-agent-data-types
# OR
yarn add --dev user-agent-data-types
```

- setting `next-env.d.ts`

```
...
/// <reference types="user-agent-data-types" /> <- add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

you may access it just using next code:

```
navigator['userAgentData']
```

The full code in my Angular application is here:

```
export interface NavigatorUAData {
  readonly brands: NavigatorUABrandVersion[];
  readonly mobile: boolean;
  readonly platform: string;
}

get isMobileDevice(): boolean {
  let userAgentData;
  let probablyIPhone;
  try {
    userAgentData = <NavigatorUAData>navigator['userAgentData'];
    probablyIPhone = navigator['userAgent'].split(' ').includes('iPhone');
  } catch (error) {}
  return userAgentData
         ? (userAgentData.mobile || probablyIPhone)
         : this.isSmallTouchDevice;
}

get isSmallTouchDevice(): boolean {
  return (window.screen.width < 769)
         && (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0));
}
```

Comment: I just tried something similar out in the TS playground: `type A = { m: number }; const a: A = { m: 1 }; a["nope"] = 1;` and it gave a type error: `Property 'nope' does not exist on type 'A'`. How does your solution work?

Comment: Please [edit] that into your post instead of putting it in the comments. Your post should be complete and up-to-date.